# How to load ppt and csv files into UIWebview

Tags: uiwebview, iphone

Is it possible to load and display the .csv files and .ppt files into UIWebview. If then can anyone suggest me how it can be implemented.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For loading file in UIWebView you have to create request as below:

```
[webView loadRequest:[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Question" ofType:@"csv"]]]];
```

Same is also applicable for PPT, PDF etc.

Comment: Thanks for your response,so how the CSV data will be displayed  in the UIWebview(i mean in which format)

Comment: It would display like excel sheet, row and col structure.

Comment: Thanks very much.It is showing the data in the default grey background of the webview

Comment: Will UIWebview support .pptm(PowerPoint 2007 Macro-Enabled XML Presentation.) files